# heroku issues on custom reactjs application deployed

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have used the heroku cli to post my reactJS application:
but this is the result after deployed to heroku and I dont seem to get what may be causing it

```
2019-11-25T23:51:33.659355+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 72% dependencies optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.659471+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 73% advanced dependencies optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.659585+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 73% after dependencies optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.659809+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 71% chunk graph
2019-11-25T23:51:33.662907+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 71% after chunk graph
2019-11-25T23:51:33.662998+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 71% after chunk graph WebAssemblyModulesPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.663273+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 74% optimizing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.663392+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 74% basic module optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.663511+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 75% module optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.663591+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 75% advanced module optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.663666+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% after module optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664006+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664050+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization EnsureChunkConditionsPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664120+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization RemoveEmptyChunksPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664187+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization MergeDuplicateChunksPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664373+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% chunk optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664639+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% advanced chunk optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.664726+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% advanced chunk optimization SplitChunksPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.669491+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% advanced chunk optimization RemoveEmptyChunksPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.669813+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% after chunk optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.670044+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 78% module and chunk tree optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.670206+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 78% after module and chunk tree optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.670428+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 79% basic chunk modules optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.670556+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 80% chunk modules optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.670693+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 80% advanced chunk modules optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.670696+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 81% after chunk modules optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.671155+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 81% module reviving
2019-11-25T23:51:33.671230+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 81% module reviving RecordIdsPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.671357+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 82% module order optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.671481+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 82% advanced module order optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.671691+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 83% before module ids
2019-11-25T23:51:33.671699+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 83% before module ids NamedModulesPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.674280+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 83% module ids
2019-11-25T23:51:33.674415+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 84% module id optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.674496+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 84% module id optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675075+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk reviving
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675131+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk reviving RecordIdsPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675368+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk order optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675451+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk order optimization OccurrenceOrderChunkIdsPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675620+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% before chunk ids
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675675+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% before chunk ids NamedChunksPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.675926+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% chunk id optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.676154+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% after chunk id optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.676670+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules
2019-11-25T23:51:33.676744+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules RecordIdsPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.676973+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks
2019-11-25T23:51:33.677036+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks RecordIdsPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.677117+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% hashing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.689543+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% after hashing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.689633+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% after hashing HotModuleReplacementPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.690230+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 89% record hash
2019-11-25T23:51:33.690308+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 89% module assets processing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.690605+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 90% chunk assets processing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.703395+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 90% additional chunk assets processing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.703407+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 90% additional chunk assets processing HotModuleReplacementPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.704348+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 91% recording
2019-11-25T23:51:33.704431+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 91% recording HotModuleReplacementPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.705232+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% additional asset processing
2019-11-25T23:51:33.705493+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% chunk asset optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.705774+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:33.705906+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.706112+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:33.706557+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin bundle.js generate SourceMap
2019-11-25T23:51:34.708270+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin resolve sources
2019-11-25T23:51:34.709060+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin bundle.js attach SourceMap
2019-11-25T23:51:34.736856+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:34.737123+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% asset optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:34.737366+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after asset optimization
2019-11-25T23:51:34.737683+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after seal
2019-11-25T23:51:34.738837+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting
2019-11-25T23:51:34.738966+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin
2019-11-25T23:51:34.858597+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting
2019-11-25T23:51:34.859678+00:00 app[web.1]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 100%
2019-11-25T23:51:34.859765+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875058+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: b57e93bf013511740ba5
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875062+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack 4.41.2
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875064+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: 7597ms
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875066+00:00 app[web.1]: Built at: 11/25/2019 11:51:34 PM
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875069+00:00 app[web.1]: Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875071+00:00 app[web.1]: bundle.js   3.09 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875073+00:00 app[web.1]: index.html  691 bytes          [emitted]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875075+00:00 app[web.1]: Entrypoint main = bundle.js
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875077+00:00 app[web.1]: [./assets/css/card.css] 874 bytes {main} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875079+00:00 app[web.1]: [./assets/css/nav.css] 871 bytes {main} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875081+00:00 app[web.1]: [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./assets/css/card.css] 2.99 KiB {main} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875084+00:00 app[web.1]: [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./assets/css/nav.css] 11.9 KiB {main} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875086+00:00 app[web.1]: [./src/App.jsx] 172 bytes {main} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875088+00:00 app[web.1]: [./src/index.jsx] 203 bytes {main} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875090+00:00 app[web.1]: + 37 hidden modules
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875092+00:00 app[web.1]: Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875094+00:00 app[web.1]: 1 asset
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875095+00:00 app[web.1]: Entrypoint undefined = index.html
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875098+00:00 app[web.1]: [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html] 852 bytes {0} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875100+00:00 app[web.1]: [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875101+00:00 app[web.1]: [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
2019-11-25T23:51:34.875103+00:00 app[web.1]: + 1 hidden module
2019-11-25T23:51:35.039912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-25T23:51:35.016071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-11-25T23:52:08.769306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=livenotes.herokuapp.com request_id=98d421e3-645e-49a1-8c2c-3a90e1cc7209 fwd="142.44.173.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-25T23:52:10.111422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=livenotes.herokuapp.com request_id=4d2d2f37-c65c-4d20-bb6b-8b0e27de95d0 fwd="142.44.173.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-25T23:55:03.488451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=livenotes.herokuapp.com request_id=ab1b3a8a-7ea0-4059-a7fe-9240598ac633 fwd="142.44.173.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-25T23:55:05.120970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=livenotes.herokuapp.com request_id=2adcd3a2-289f-416c-8d80-55a43671a173 fwd="142.44.173.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I saw this after using heroku logs --tail
and it seems this information is the reason why the application crashes.
Need help to resolve this issue so my app works. thanks